# Read a sample at a specified time with AVAssetReader/alternative

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation, movie

I am trying to get the raw bitmap from a video. Using AVAssetReader gets me there. However, I can only read from a video serially. I am looking for a way to read from an arbitrary point within the file, such as starting in the middle of a video. I don't think AVAssetReader allows this, but curious if there is another method I've overlooked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a property timerange that you can use for your AVAssetreader. Based on the documentation it says 'The time range of the asset that should be read' however it should be noted that once reading has started this value cannot be changed.